# Отображать месяц и год в datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

На странице бутстраповский `datetimepicker`. В первый раз когда кликаю - все корректно. Кликаю второй раз - он мне отображает не то что нужно. Отображает выбор даты, хотя мне нужен только месяц. `Bootstrap 3`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Тут уже косяк**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(
            {
                viewMode: 'months',
                format: 'MM/YYYY',
                locale: 'ru'
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(
        {
            viewMode: 'months',
            format: 'MM/YYYY',
            locale: 'ru'
        }
    );

    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.show", function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("DateTimePicker").viewMode("months");
    });
```